# Users automatically get subscribed to Auto renewable in-app purchase after downloading app from the App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I have developed [an app for my blog](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/igeeksblog/id1135179420?mt=8) that works great in sandbox mode for auto-renewable subscriptions. However, when we deploy to app store it doesn’t work.

- I have three auto-renewal subscriptions in my app as monthly, six months, and yearly subscription. All of them are configured and approved in iTunes Connect. If user buy in-app purchase, we hide advertisement from the app and allow unlimited bookmarks. My sandbox test account is working fine with in-app purchase testing.
- After testing app thoroughly, I submitted app to the iTunes Connect and its approved by Apple. Once app is approved and user download it from the App Store, user automatically becomes subscribed to the in-app purchase and advertisement doesn’t display on the app.
- I test the auto renewable in-app purchase on my device with sand box account and there is no problem at all. However, when user download same version of the App from the App Store then he automatically get subscribed to the in-app purchase and locked features (hide ad and unlimited bookmarks) are automatically get enabled.

Comment: I suspect that your problem statement isn’t quite right;  users can’t get subscribed automatically; The purchase process requires user interaction. What is possible is that your app is incorrectly determining that the user is subscribed. You need to look at the logic you use to determine an active subscription and determine why it is false triggering.

Comment: I installed your app. I didn’t get advertising but I was not promoted to purchase the subscription, so I suspect that your subscription checking logic is broken. You should edit your question to show the relevant code. Also your app frequently crashes while scrolling up while items are loading.

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).